# gnuplot: constant expression required - but only first time in a for-loop

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I wrote a gnuplot script "fs_create_stats_table_file.gp" which always fails when I run it for the first time. But after one crash I can use it without any problem in the same gnuplot session. The values ​​for both variables (value_line, value_line_param) appear to be correct. But when I first call "print @value_line" within the for-loop the script crashes.

Script:

```
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# db      
S ta      tb  
1 1979.2  2027
1 1598.6  1591.4
1 1430.8  1401.6
1 1544.7  1923.7
1 1953.3  1677
1 1288.8  1311.1
1 1741.3  1689.3
1 1791.1  2015.8
EOD

DATA_BLOCKS = "db"
LABELS = "ta tb"

gp_stats_labels = "STATS_records STATS_min STATS_max STATS_index_min STATS_index_max"  
    
header_line = "type"

do for [stats_label in gp_stats_labels] {
    header_line = header_line."\t".stats_label
}

do for [block in DATA_BLOCKS] {
    print "# ".block
    print header_line
    
    value_line = ""
    
    do for [selected_label in LABELS] {
        value_line = "sprintf( \"%s"
        value_line_param = "selected_label"
        
        stats $Data i block u (column(selected_label)) nooutput
        
        do for [stats_label in gp_stats_labels] {
            if ( strstrt( stats_label, "records" ) > 0 ) || ( strstrt( stats_label, "index" ) > 0 ) {
                value_line = value_line."\t%d"
            } else {
                value_line = value_line."\t%.4f"
            }
            
            value_line_param = value_line_param.", ".stats_label
        }    
        
        value_line = value_line."\", ".value_line_param." )"
        
        print value_line
        print value_line_param
        
        print @value_line
    }
    
    print ""
    print ""
}
```

Error:

```
gnuplot> load "fs_create_stats_table_file.gp"
         "fs_create_stats_table_file.gp" line 34: warning: value_line is not a string variable
# db
type    STATS_records   STATS_min       STATS_max       STATS_index_min STATS_index_max
sprintf( "%s    %d      %.4f    %.4f    %d      %d", selected_label, STATS_records, STATS_min, STATS_max, STATS_index_min, STATS_index_max )
selected_label, STATS_records, STATS_min, STATS_max, STATS_index_min, STATS_index_max
         "fs_create_stats_table_file.gp" line 61: constant expression required

gnuplot>
```

Comment: What is the reason that you assemble the `STATS_` values in a complex manner into a string and printing them via macro instead of directly printing the values via `sprintf()`?

Comment: If I print the values ​​directly, a newline character is automatically appended. So I can't print a table this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I cannot tell what's wrong with your script. Well, some issue with the `@`macro...

Maybe, you want to try a slightly different version using `eval` (check `help evaluate`).

**Script:**

```
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# db
S ta      tb
1 1979.2  2027
1 1598.6  1591.4
1 1430.8  1401.6
1 1544.7  1923.7
1 1953.3  1677
1 1288.8  1311.1
1 1741.3  1689.3
1 1791.1  2015.8


# db2
S ta      tb
1 1979.2  2027
1 1598.6  1591.4
1 1430.8  1401.6
1 1544.7  1923.7
1 1953.3  1677
1 1288.8  1311.1
1 1741.3  1689.3
1 1791.1  2015.8
EOD

DATA_BLOCKS = "db db2"
LABELS = "ta tb"

gp_stats_labels = "STATS_records STATS_min STATS_max STATS_index_min STATS_index_max"  
header_line     = "type"

do for [stats_label in gp_stats_labels] {
    header_line = header_line."\t".stats_label
}

do for [block in DATA_BLOCKS] {
    print "# ".block
    print header_line

    do for [selected_label in LABELS] {
        value_line = 'sprintf( "%s'
        value_line_param = "selected_label"
        
        stats $Data i block u (column(selected_label)) nooutput
        
        do for [stats_label in gp_stats_labels] {
            if ( strstrt( stats_label, "records" ) > 0 ) || ( strstrt( stats_label, "index" ) > 0 ) {
                value_line = value_line."\t%d"
            } else {
                value_line = value_line."\t%.4f"
            }
            value_line_param = value_line_param.", ".stats_label
        }    
        value_line = value_line."\", ".value_line_param." )"
        
        # print value_line
        # print value_line_param
        eval("print ".value_line)
    }
    print ""
    print ""
}
```

**Result:**

```
# db
type    STATS_records   STATS_min       STATS_max       STATS_index_min STATS_index_max
ta      8       1288.8000       1979.2000       5       0
tb      8       1311.1000       2027.0000       5       0


# db2
type    STATS_records   STATS_min       STATS_max       STATS_index_min STATS_index_max
ta      8       1288.8000       1979.2000       5       0
tb      8       1311.1000       2027.0000       5       0
```

**Addition:** shortened solution which will give the same result as above. Maybe can be further optimized.

**Script:** (without data section, take the one from above)

```
BLOCKS    = "db db2"
LABELS    = "ta tb"
STATS     = "STATS_records, STATS_min, STATS_max, STATS_index_min, STATS_index_max"
STATS_str = "STATS_records\tSTATS_min\tSTATS_max\tSTATS_index_min\tSTATS_index_max"
HEADER    = "type\t".STATS_str

do for [BLOCK in BLOCKS] {
    print "# ".BLOCK
    print HEADER
    do for [LABEL in LABELS] {
        stats $Data i BLOCK u (column(LABEL)) nooutput
        print sprintf("%s\t%d\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%d\t%d",LABEL,@STATS)
    }
    print ""; print ""
}
```